# Is it possible to add a custom "editor" as an add-on?

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on

I would like to create an add-on to add a new type of node editor to blender.
but before doing so, want to make sure I'm not diving into something that the current version simply doesn't allow.

Is this something that would require making a custom version of blender? 
or can it be achieved via python script add-on? If so, can anyone please shed some light on this?

[image: Desired Editor location]

Comment: Yes, it's possible to add new editor types. For instance the [LuxCore integration into Blender](https://github.com/LuxCoreRender/BlendLuxCore/tree/master/nodes) does that for its own material nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RobertGützkow. :-D