# Can I create my own area in Blender?

Tags: python, node-editor

With Blender I can change the type of area (shader editor, 3d viewport...) by clicking on its upper left icon. Does Blender apis allow me to create my own area type and using the Blender node-editor, with my own custom node types I can add with shift+A ?

[image]

Comment: The only custom editor you can add with python is a node editor. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185254/how-to-create-custom-editors-with-python or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170526/is-it-possible-to-add-a-custom-editor-as-an-add-on